# How to get multiple matched values from the array object using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to get multiple matched values from the array object?

my scenario is:

```
var studentData = [
                 {name:"Ram",htno:1245},
                 {name:"mohan",htno:1246},
                 {name:"madhu",htno:1247},
                 {name:"ranga",htno:1248}
              ];

var studentsToCompare = ["mohan","ranga"];


Expected output:
var matchedStudentsdata = [
                 {name:"mohan",htno:1246},
                 {name:"ranga",htno:1248}
              ];
```

Thanks 
Rambabu Bommisetti

Comment: What have you tried? What basis you are calculating this matchedValue?

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: Try MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array or W3Schools https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use filter on `student` array:**

```js
var student = [{name:"Ram",htno:1245},{name:"mohan",htno:1246},{name:"madhu",htno:1247},{name:"ranga",htno:1248}]

var matchedvalues = ["mohan","ranga"];

var matchedStudentsdata = student.filter(function(stu) {
  return matchedvalues.indexOf(stu.name) > -1;
})

console.log(matchedStudentsdata)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `filter()` like the following:

```js
var student = [{name:"Ram",htno:1245},{name:"mohan",htno:1246},{name:"madhu",htno:1247},{name:"ranga",htno:1248}]

var matchedvalues = ["mohan","ranga"];

var matchedStudentsdata = student.filter(stu => matchedvalues.includes(stu.name));

console.log(matchedStudentsdata);
```

Comment: great solution for me, I have used map function earlier, because of you i came to know use of filter.

Comment: @RambabuBommisetti, you are most welcome. It is always good to know that the solution is helpful to you. Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.....thanks for the comment.